# Cause: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, gradle

Сразу прошу прощение за возможный дубликат, но как я понял из анализа ответов в сети, на этот момент может влиять множество факторов. Ни одно из решений не дало результата.

Ситуация в следующем.
При загрузке пустого проекта (с пустым файлом build.gradle) возникает такое сообщение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В настройках прокси - сервера указана ссылка на системный сценарий авторизации - Automatic Proxy Configuration URL. Проверка соединения (на примере сайта http://ya.ru) отрабатывает успешно.

В файле gradle.properties по адресу C:\Users\<мое имя>\.gradle\ указаны параметры авторизации аналогичные тем, с которыми я захожу на локальную машину (находится в домене).

Я так понимаю нет локальных сертификатов. Как - то их можно установить через интерфейс самой IDE? Или причина может быть в чем-то другом? Что еще можно и нужно проверить?

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке скопируй и вставь как текст.

Comment: @RomanC Cause: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty - Но оно есть на изображении и в заголовке